# (Python) I am having trouble Finding the integer values form [“a”, 1 , 4 ,6 ,”b” , “d” ,7 , “o”] list using list comprehension method

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Here is the following code that I have executed but the answer I desired should be like [1, 4, 6, 7] but instead the output is [False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False]...
Please guide me on how can I get the desired output.

```
a_list = ["a", 1, 4, 6, "b", "d", 7, "o"]
result_list = [(type(x) == int) for x in a_list]
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long way of doing this and a short way:
Short:

```
a_list = ["a", 1, 4, 6, "b", "d", 7, "o"]
result_list = [x for x in a_list if (type(x) == int)]
print(result_list)
```

Long (but easier to read):

```
a_list = ["a", 1, 4, 6, "b", "d", 7, "o"]
result_list = []
for i in a_list:
    if type(i) == int:
        result_list.append(i)
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

`[(type(x) == int) for x in a_list]` means: fill the list with the values of `(type(x) == int)` (which are booleans), where the elements `x` come from `a_list`. Thus, this list comprehension creates a list of booleans.

You want to get all the *items of `a_list`* that satisfy some criterion. So, use this:

```
[
  x # get all items of `a_list`...
  for x in a_list
  if isinstance(x, int) # ...that satisfy this
]
```

Here's why you should use `isinstance(x, int)` instead of `type(x) == int`: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance).

Answer (score 2):

you did well, the reason why print(result_list) returns boolean values is because its returning the result of the comparison done in type (x) == int.

In order to return the int values in the list, you need to say for x where x is the value in a_list, if its of type int, store that value in a new list. I named the result list for integers result_num_list See code snippet below:

```
a_list = ["a", 1, 4, 6, "b", "d", 7, "o"]
result_num_list = [x for x in a_list if type(x)==int]
print(result_num_list)
```

The output will be [1, 4, 6, 7]